# NiFi SpringContextProcessor using @Configuration instead of XML

Tags: spring, apache-nifi

I am in the process of creating a Spring-based processor in NiFi using [NiFi's SpringContextProcessor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.spring.SpringContextProcessor/additionalDetails.html). SpringContextProcessor requires "Application Context config path" property to be set, which points to an XML configuration file. Spring has shifted away from XML based configs and towards @Configuration approach. How can NiFi's SpringContextProcessor be created using @Configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the processor currently now relies on ClassPathXmpApplicationContext. We can certainly add support for @Configured. However with that said you can easily have a place holder XML file that contains pointers to @Configured and other mechanisms provided by Spring (i.e., 'import').
Please raise JIRA to add @Configured support here -https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/

Comment: can you guide me to any link on how can I implement SpringContextProcessor in Apache Nifi..unable to find a working example

Comment: I'm interested in using a small Spring service inside a NiFi processor.  The service will be uni-directional, _at the start_, and simply retrieve data from a REST endpoint.  Oleg, would you recommend I mimic your Camel based approach presented [here](https://github.com/olegz/si-demo) or is there a simpler solution, given [NIFI-2909](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2909) ?